# Scraping two pages at the same time : pandas error

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to save movie reviews and movie's title from those two pages.

```
https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=~
https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/basic.nhn?code=~
```

And when I ran this code, and opened the csv file.

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 6), indices imply (2, 10)
>   [image: saved csv file]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urljoin
import pandas as pd
import requests

#url_base = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=25917&type=after&page=1'
base_url = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=' #review page
base_url2 = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/basic.nhn?code=' #movie title
pages =['177374','164102']

#print(soup.find_all('div', 'score_reple'))
#div = soup.find('h3', 'h_movie')

df = pd.DataFrame()
for n in pages:
    # Create url
    url = base_url + n
    url2 = base_url2 + n

    # Parse data using BS
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url2)

    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    reple = soup.find_all('div', 'score_reple')
    res2 = requests.get(url2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res2.text, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find('h3', 'h_movie')
    #ratesc = soup.find('','')
    #story=rname.getText()
    #data = [title,reple]
    data = {'title':[title], 'reviewn':[reple]}
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data), sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('./title.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

How do I fix this code?

Comment: why are you using BeautifulSoup if you have selenium ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now is clean ....just remove the tags with something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
#from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urljoin
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

#url_base = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=25917&type=after&page=1'
base_url = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=' #review page
base_url2 = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/basic.nhn?code=' #movie title
pages =['177374','164102']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for n in pages:
    # Create url
    url = base_url + n
    url2 = base_url2 + n

    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    reple = soup.find("span", {"id":re.compile("^_filtered_ment")}).getText()
    res2 = requests.get(url2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res2.text, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find('h3', 'h_movie')
    for a in title.find_all('a'):
        #print(a.text)
        title=a.text

    data = {'title':[title], 'reviewn':[reple]}
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data))

df.to_csv('./title.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

I added import re for regex the class _filtered_ment_*

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try for cleaning it up is to first convert to string and then place constraints based on the html like the below:

```
title = str(soup.find('h3', 'h_movie'))
start = '" title="'
end = '                                     ,                   2018">'
newTitle = title[title.find(start)+len(start):title.rfind(end)]
```

Then try the same thing on the review section. You'll want to narrow down the result set and then convert to string where the review sections are and place constraints on that.

Then you'll have the data cleaned up and ready to add into the DataFrame.

Hopefully this helps get you on the right path!